# How to run the xml pull parser example given in Android developer website

Tags: xmlpullparser

I am trying to run the sample code given in Android developer website in Eclipse.
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

But I am not able to run it. I get an error that "import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException.html" cannot be resolved.

I downloaded the jar (from www extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/download/old_versions/) and changed the build path to PullParser11.jar but I still get the same error and cannot run.

I am new to Java and Android so maybe I am making a silly mistake. Kindly help me with this problem so that I can run the parser code.

Thank you for your time and help.

Madhu

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if this is just a nasty typo. The code on the Android website would try to import the class `html` from the package `XmlPullParserException` which just doesn't make sense. Try removing the `.html` and you should be fine.

```
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried removing .html but it didn't work even then. I wrote a simple parser with pattern and matcher classes which is good enough for my use now.